# Choose every legal java identifier

Tags: java, identifier

I'm practicing a java quiz and failed to answer this quiz correctly.
I thought that I checked (with checkmarks in front) all possible java identifiers but the test said that I got it wrong.

Can you tell me what is the correct answer because the web site does not provide answer? Below there is quiz and the answers I gave.

> ### Quiz of legal identifier
>
> Which of the following can be used in a Java program as identifiers?
>   Check all of the identifiers that are legal.

- ☐ println
- ☑ B4
- ☑ sum_of_data
- ☑ _average
- ☐ 42isThesolution
- ☐ "hello"
- ☐ for
- ☑ first-name
- ☑ AnnualSalary
- ☑ ABC

Answer (score 3):

Well `println` is a common method identifier (it's part of library classes but that doesn't make it something special like a keyword). Additionally you could use `int println = 0;` if you wanted. Poor style but legal Java.

Additionally `first-name` would be parsed as two identifiers and the subtraction operator. So it should not be checked.

To address the `System.out.println()` method vs identifier issue:
`println` is an identifier for a set of overloaded methods in the `PrintStream` class of which `System.out` is an instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it keeps saying wrong even though adding the println

Comment: `first-name` is not a valid identifier because identifiers cannot contain a minus character

Comment: @Erwin yep you are right. After unchecking first-name, it said correct. I thought -(minus) is restricted only in the beginning. Anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`println` CAN be an identifier. `System.out.println` is not an identifier but rather a method called by `PrintStream` through `System.out`. So for example `println(5)` is not going to be doing anything. But `System.out.println(5)` will actually write `5` to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Legal Identifiers: sum_of_data, B4, println, AnnualSalary, ABC, _average